# How to refer to an inner class inside a list in Java

Tags: java, list, inner-classes

after messing around with parsing a JSON response with GSON for a day, I finally figured out how to get my javabeans right in order to extract my data from the response. This is the layout of my nested classes and lists:

```
    public class LocationContainer {

    public class paging {
        private String previous;
        private String next;
    }


    private List<Datas> data;

    public class Datas {


        private String message;
        private String id;
        private String created_time;

        public class Tags {
            private List<Data> datas;
            public class Data {
                private String id;
                private String name;
            }

        }

        public class Application {

                private String id;
                private String name;

        }

        public class From {
            private String id;
            private String name;

        }

        public class Place {
            private String id;
            private String name;
            public class Location {
                private int longitude;
                private int latitude;
                        }


        }

    }

}
```

Now I am trying to get a hold of the name string inside the place class and the created_time string, but since I am quite a noob, I can't seem to figure it out.

I was able to extract the created_time string by using

```
String time = gson.toJson(item.data.get(1).created_time);
```

However using

```
String name = gson.toJson(item.data.get(1).Place.name);
```

doesnt work.

The item class is an instance of LocationContainer filled with the output from GSON.
Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`created_time` is a member *variable* of `Data`, so your first line is fine.

However, `Place` is *not* a member variable, it's just a class definition.  You probably need to instantiate a member variable inside your `Data` class, e.g.:

```
private Place place;
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you Sir!
gson.toJson(item.data.get(1).place.name was my reference to the name string after inserting private Place place; into my data class.